# How to detect when a QDockWidget is moved out of a QMainWindow?

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

There is a signal which allows the user to know where a QDockWidget has been moved **inside** a QMainWindow :

```
void dockLocationChanged(Qt::DockWidgetArea area)
```

The problem is that this signal is not fired when a QDockWidget is moved **out of** the QMainWindow (either by dragging or by double-clicking the dockwidget's title bar).

Is there a way to detect that event, **without reimplementing** `moveEvent()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `floating` property exactly for that purpose, and a `topLevelChanged` signal.

Comment: That's interesting. The docs don't say when `topLevelChanged` was added, but I remember wondering exactly what the OP asked back before Qt5.

Comment: Oh you're right, my question is not complete. I'll accept it anyway, but unfortunately, this signal is not emitted when you tabify a dock widget with another one already out of the main window... (neither is the signal `dockLocationChanged()`)

Comment: Changing `floating` property using `setFloating()` method, is not emitting `topLevelChanged()` signal. Is that expected?